# Visual C++ 2015 Runtimes

Tags: runtime

What is Visual C++ 2015 Runtime used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This are run-time components that you need  to  install to run  applications written/compiled in Visual C++ 2015

[Here's](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ph/download/details.aspx?id=48145) the link to install the  run-time components for Visual C++ 2015